# Pointer reference not stored in a struct in my go program

Tags: go

I am new to go-lang and I try to figure out how to work properly with structs and dependency injection. I am a bit stuck because I am not able to properly store a reference to another struct.

Here's my method that generates a CommandController. There is a valid reference to iris.Application.

```
func ProvideCommandController(application *iris.Application, commandRepository command.CommandRepository) (*interfaces.CommandController, error) {
commandController := interfaces.CommandController{}
commandController.Init(application, commandRepository)
commandController.Start()
return &commandController, nil
```

}

The struct looks like this:

```
type CommandController struct {
    commandRepository command.CommandRepository
    app   *iris.Application
}

func (c CommandController) Init(app *iris.Application, repository command.CommandRepository) {
    c.app = app
    c.commandRepository = repository
}

func (c CommandController) Start() {
    c.app.Get("/command", c.readAll)
    c.app.Get("/command/{id:string}/execute", c.executeCommand)

    c.app.Run(iris.Addr(":8080"))
}
```

When the `ProvideCommandController` function gets executed I can debug and observe that all references look good. Unfortunately, `commandController.Start()`fails because of `c.app` is nil.

What piece of understanding do I miss? Somehow, the stored reference get's deleted between the Init and the Start function call.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Your CommandController receiver is a value receiver. Try to replace it with a pointer receiver like: func(c *CommandController) { . . . }. This is because you are mutating the receiver itself but currently your methods duplicate it and mutate the duplicate, not original receiver itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
func (c CommandController) Init(app *iris.Application, repository command.CommandRepository)
```

to

```
func (c *CommandController) Init(app *iris.Application, repository command.CommandRepository)
```

since `Init` receives `c` by value in your version, any changes it makes to `c` don't appear outside of the `Init` method.

Comment: awesome...Thanks,  this makes sense. Why should I favour a call by value over a call by reference?